# 'var' and 'let' in Typescript 1.5

Tags: compilation, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

What exactly is the difference between using either '**var**' or '**let**' in Typescript? I know that 'let' allows the variable to be defined further into a scope without it being used outside of said scope. That is obviously a nice advantage for iterators in for loops. I know this is an ES6 definition, so compiling to ES6 should look nearly identical in terms of 'var' and 'let'.

But, when it compiles down into ES5 javascript which doesn't support 'let', what exactly is happening? Are there oddly named variables that the compiler creates so that it prevents using said variables in the context of the Typescript file? What happens in situations where you define many 'let' variables throughout a function? Is there a performance impact I should be concerned about?

Basically, **what is happening when typescript compiles let variables to ES5 javascript?**

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for Programmers.SE: this site is about software development concepts, but you are asking about a specific implementation detail of a particular language. If you'd be interested in how compilers in general might implement lexical scope, that might be on topic here (but possibly too broad). Since you're essentially asking about a programming tool, I'm voting to migrate to Stack Overflow, which seems to be better suited for this kind of question.

Comment: I think this is a great question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way to find answers to these type of questions to try it out in the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/).

TypeScript renames the variables within the block scope. There's no performance overhead compared to using regular variables defined with `var`.

This code:

```
var i = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}
i++;
```

Compiles to:

```
var i = 0;
for (var i_1 = 0; i_1 < 5; i_1++) { }
i++;
```

[Here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html) is some more information regarding `let`.

Comment: You're right, that's probably the best way of digging into something like that. Interestingly too, If you try to throw in a var i_1, it will automatically make the let into i_2. Kinda neat.