# Why do var and let produce different outputs in closures?

Tags: javascript

Consider these 2 snippets:

**With `let`**:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(i);
 }, 100)
}
```

**With `var`**:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //HERE
    setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(i);
 }, 100)
}
```

From my understanding, `let` only affects the scoping of the variables, so why are the outputs of the 2 loops should be same, so why does `let` print 0-9 and `var` prints 10 10 times?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572895/what-is-the-difference-between-var-and-let-in-typescript

Comment: Cause a for loop actually creates a new block scope in each iteration.

Comment: check this link : 
http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/keyword-var-vs-let/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a timeout in your loop, none of your logs are being called until the entire loop is finished.

After the loop is finished, the value of `i` is 10 if you use `var`.

But `let` is block scoped, meaning it's the same value anywhere in the loop, even in an async function like setTimeout (unless you manually change it inside the loop) - because the loop creates a new scope on each iteration, it's almost like each iteration creates a new "instance" of the i variable when you use `let`, whereas using `var` each loop is using the same instance of the `i` variable.