# How it works parameter-passing into typescript?

Tags: typescript, parameter-passing

Below there're two pieces of code. I searched a question like this but I haven't found yet.
So I don't understand why in my first piece of code my function found my parameter, in this example *filterId*, but not in the second.

I guess it could be because filterValue is like a var declaration, [What is the difference between var and let in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572895/what-is-the-difference-between-var-and-let-in-typescript), instead of a block-scoped, as let. Is it ok this idea?

This is works:

```
    getServiceAreasFiltered (page: number, filterValue: string): Observable {
      const filterId = filterValue;
      this._http.post(resource, content).pipe(
        flatMap(area => area.results),
        filter((area: ServiceAreaListItem) => area.guid === filterId),
      ).subscribe(x => x);
    }
```

This is not works:

```
    getServiceAreasFiltered (page: number, filterValue?: string): Observable {
      this._http.post(resource, content).pipe(
        flatMap(area => area.results),
        filter((area: ServiceAreaListItem) => area.guid === filterValue),
      ).subscribe(x => x);
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error and I don't know why but now the second piece of code works as the first piece.  Despite this, my question is still the same: are parameters-passing block-scoped or function-scoped?

Comment: Block-scoped or function-scoped for the function parameters? It is the same thing.